# I want to switch to Lubuntu, how can I take all of my programs/files with me?

Tags: lubuntu

I'm going to switch from Ubuntu to Lubuntu for my HTPC/server because I hear Lubuntu is faster, what's a (preferrably easy) way to take all of my files and programs with me?

I'm very new to Linux and I'm not sure if I could survive the ordeal of installing my few programs again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather re installing  LUbuntu install LXDE in your current ubuntu

to install type following commands in terminal:-

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

After installing reboot your system 
[image]

[image]

source :- http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-install-the-lxde-desktop

Comment: Well, that sounds like it'll do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, do you think you could help with this question? Kind of urgent. http://askubuntu.com/questions/484823/ive-lost-connection-to-my-network-after-a-failed-attempt-at-a-bridged-connectio

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind.